# IE how to open blob object in new Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Hi any one have idea about how to open an blob object in IE new Tab

```
var blob = base64toBlob(blobresponse);
    if (blob) {
        if (window.navigator &&
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.target = "_blank"
            a.download = "test.pdf";
            a.click();
        } else {
            var objectUrl = URL
                .createObjectURL(blob);
            window
                .open(objectUrl);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, IE has a problem with opening blob URL in new tab.
But you can force it to download.

```
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob , 'test.pdf');
```

But if you want to view PDF in IE, you can try to use pdf.js ([link](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js))

Comment: but i wants to open rather then download

Comment: @gayathri no way)))

Comment: @gayathri If you want to view pdf in ie, you can try to use pdf.js => https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: but i dont wants to use any other plug in this will makes complex anyway thank you so far i tried many ways and forums there is no answer for this and also even stack overflow also got one reply so its not possible i guess becz of security issues of IE . but thank you @Alex

Comment: Is there any way to restrict to open the blank new tab? Think it is useless to open a blank tab unneccessarily

Comment: @GayathriMohan got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using iframe

```
var blob = base64toBlob(blobresponse);

if (blob) {
    var tab = window.open();
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    if (window.navigator &&
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // for IE
        var iframe= document.createElement("iframe");
        tab.document.body.appendChild(iframe);  
        iframe.src = objectUrl;
        iframe.setAttribute("style","width:100%;height:100%");                      
    } else { // for Chrome           
        tab.location.href = objectUrl;
    }
}
```